# User information not getting into MYSQL db

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, web

m making this user signup form and linking the user email name and password tot he table in mysql DB, but it's not showing any row in mySQl DB.

**Here is the code:**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query_input = mysql_query($connect,"INSERT INTO    user_basic_info(username,email,password)VALUES('$username','$email','$password')");

    if($query_input){ 

        echo "done and dope";

    }
   else{


        echo "no";
    }
}
```

Comment: Post a code, because there's no any

Comment: I can't see the code.

Comment: sorry i just edit it

Comment: Where is `$connect`?

Comment: almost all the no-gos of handling PHP-login systems: the `mysql`-functions are deprecated, and in PHP7 **removed**, use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead; your code is vulnerable to **SQL-Injection** attacks - imagine the username `';DROP TABLE user_basic_info; --`; and **don't** ever store passwords as plain text. use `password_hash` and `password_verify` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have a error in your mysql_query function

```
$query_input = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_basic_info(username,email,password) VALUES('$username','$email','$password')",$connect);
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

BTW please use mysqli

```
mysqli_query("INSERT INTO user_basic_info(username,email,password)VALUES('$username','‌​$email','$password')‌​",$connect);
```

Comment: $query_input = mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO user_basic_info(username,email,password)VALUES('$username','$email','$password')");

Comment: did you put space before VALUES also?

Comment: did u change your code to mysqli version from the comments above? $connect variable should be the second parameter

Comment: i am asking about $connect. did you put it after your query or before the query?? and where is your database connection file??

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should try to use `MySQLi` or [PDO (tutorial here)](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query_input = mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO    user_basic_info(username,email,password)VALUES('$username','$email','$password')");

    if($query_input){ 

        echo "done and dope";

    }
    else{


        echo "no";
    }
    //close db connection
    mysqli_close($connect);
}
```

Comment: yes my code is exactly like this but its not working as when i enter the data   the data does not get store in the Database table

Comment: @NadeemFayyaz the code is working on my side. Please post your form code.